# CSV Writer stops writing data after 21 rows

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I have this huge list of products and prices and I'm trying to export it onto a CSV file for easier readability, but for some reason, it only writes in 21 lines of the data and then stops.

This is the current code:

```py
for x in range(1, 20):
    url = (f'website.com/page{x}')
    page = requests.get(url)

    soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
    articles = soup.find_all('article', class_='product-grid-item')

    with open('website.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
        
        thewriter = writer(f)
        header = ['Title', 'Price']
        thewriter.writerow(header)

        for article in articles:
            title = article.find('h3', class_='product-item-title').text.strip()
            price = article.find('div', class_='product-item-price').text.strip()
            
            products = [title, price]
            thewriter.writerow(products)
```

The list of products comes out to be over 200 products but it only prints the last 21. Am I doing something wrong I'm new to web scraping and exporting data into csv?

Comment: It says `for x in range(1, 20):` why are you expecting it to do more?

Answer (score 0):

This is because at the top it says

```py
for x in range(1, 20):
```

This will make it start from 1 and loop until 20. If you want it to loop more times increase that number.

To learn more about the range function in python I recommend [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp)

**Syntax:**

`range(start, stop, step)`

**Parameter Values:**

**Start**: `An integer number specifying at which position to start. Default is 0. (optional)`

**Stop**: `An integer number specifying at which position to stop (not included). (Required)`

**Step**: `An integer number specifying the incrementation. Default is 1 (Optional)`

Comment: So how should I write it to get data from multiple website pages and still be able to export all the data onto a CSV file?

Comment: you can add something that just loops it for every line on the site

Comment: Well, that's what I was using 'for x in range' when I print out the data it comes out with all the products but no matter how large I make the number it only writes the final webpage of data into the CVS.

Comment: That's because it's not appending it so it replaces the existing data in the file

Answer (score 0):

This line of code was not working, only writing the last list:

```
with open('website.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
```

I changed the 'write'  call to an 'append' call and now it writes all 300+ products into the cvs file:

```
 with open('website.csv', 'a', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
```